# Xcode crashes when i try to select Routing : pedestrians in Capabilities > Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Xcode crashes when i try to select Routing : pedestrians in Capabilities > Maps

[image: xcode Project settings]
[image: xcode crash report]

Comment: Created a new project using Xcode 6.2.3 (Swift) activated Maps>Pedestrian option without any crash.

Comment: i am using xcode 6.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 and it doesn't crash, either. Fortunately, there's a workaround: you can add these settings manually via the .plist file:

[image: screenshot]