# Mac app crash while set Maps route in Capabilities

Tags: macos, app-store

I am develop Mac OSX app,everything works fine when I debug.

but I try to "Archive"-> "Distribute App" -> "Mac App Store" -> "Export App" install,the app can't open.

but close Map route is worked.
[image]

I am try this answer,but can't help me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30828234/6202715

Any people know this? Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the only way to distribute a maps-based app is through the iOS App Store or Mac App Store,so can't open.[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW41)